# Objc: Class X is implemented in both Y and Z . One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoa

I was trying to add a swift file to an existing Obj-C project and this project has some frameworks linked to it. When I add a swift file to it, it's compiling just fine but at runtime it is complaining about some swift standard classes are being implemented in both linked framework and the current project.

These duplicate class definitions are not originally from the linked frameworks but from swift standard libraries for example **libswiftFoundation.dylib**. Anyone know how to fix this?.

I'm using xcode8.3 running on sierra.

```
objc[74652]: Class _TtC8Dispatch16DispatchWorkItem is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib (0x101328e58) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100415608). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtC10Foundation20_SwiftNSCharacterSet is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x101456ab0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413708). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtC10Foundation12_DataStorage is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x10145a048) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100419258). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtC10Foundation12_NSSwiftData is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x101456b50) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004137a8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtC10Foundation25_NSErrorRecoveryAttempter is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x10145a680) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100419888). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtC10Foundation25NSFastEnumerationIterator is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x10145a720) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100419928). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtC10Foundation15NSSimpleCString is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x10145a7d8) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004199e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtC10Foundation16NSConstantString is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x10145a868) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100419a70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs18_EmptyArrayStorage is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100e990) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413870). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs20_RawNativeSetStorage is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ea40) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413920). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs17_CocoaSetIterator is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x101023a98) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x10042ed90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs27_RawNativeDictionaryStorage is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100eb08) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004139e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs24_CocoaDictionaryIterator is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x101024a98) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x10042fd90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs17NonObjectiveCBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x101026538) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100431830). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs17_stdlib_AtomicInt is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1010289a8) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100433ca0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs19_SwiftNativeNSArray is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ebe0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413ac0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs24_SwiftNativeNSDictionary is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ec48) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413b28). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs17_SwiftNativeNSSet is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ecb0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413b90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs24_SwiftNativeNSEnumerator is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ed18) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413bf8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs18_SwiftNativeNSData is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ed80) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413c60). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs26_SwiftNativeNSCharacterSet is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ede8) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413cc8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs31_stdlib_ReturnAutoreleasedDummy is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ee50) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413d30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs20_SwiftNativeNSString is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100eec8) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413da8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs19_NSContiguousString is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100ef30) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413e10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs40_SwiftNativeNSArrayWithContiguousStorage is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100efb0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413e90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f020) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413f00). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs27_ContiguousArrayStorageBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f0b0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100413f90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs14_VaListBuilder is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10102dec8) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004391c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _TtCs13VaListBuilder is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10102dfb8) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004392b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (0x101456c08) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414028). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSError is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f148) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414078). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class SwiftObject is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f198) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004140c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftValue is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f210) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414140). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNull is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f260) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414190). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSArrayBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f2b0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004141e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSDictionaryBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f300) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414230). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSSetBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f350) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414280). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSStringBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f3a0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004142d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSEnumeratorBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f3f0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414320). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSDataBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f440) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414370). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSCharacterSetBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f490) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x1004143c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[74652]: Class _SwiftNativeNSIndexSetBase is implemented in both /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/UninstalledProducts/macosx/BKMySQL.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x10100f4e0) and /Users/username/Dev/Source/build/Debug/BKServerFramework (0x100414410). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

`Note: BKServerFramework is a command line tool, ignore the name it's not a framework.`

Comment: I suspect there are two different versions of the Swift Standard Library between the linked framework and the current project. Make sure you standardize your project and all of its dependencies to a single version

Comment: @Alexander I checked both project's build settings for **Swift Language Version**  and they both are using Swift3 and also the same sdk version

Comment: @cha77a were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `BKServerFramework` was statically linked with `libswiftCore.a`. It shouldn't have been.

Comment: I removed everything from **Link binary with Libraries** and there are no other links to any binaries, but I'm still running into this issue. After your suggestion I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168539/when-building-a-swift-command-line-tool-with-associated-swift-library-why-is-the) which seems exactly like mine(I'm building a cmd-line tool too), however the solution to that question seems like not standard way of doing things.ex: Manually linking standard libs

Answer (score 0):

Add `SWIFT_FORCE_DYNAMIC_LINK_STDLIB: YES` and `SWIFT_FORCE_STATIC_LINK_STDLIB: NO` as `User-Defined Settings` in your commandline tool project's settings to prevent `BKServerFramework` from statically linking to Swift* libraries